proof using combinatorics
A child has a set of $96$ distinct blocks. Each block is one of $2$ materials (plastic, wood), $3$ sizes (small, medium, large), $4$ colours (blue, green, red, yellow), and $4$ shapes (circle, hexagon, square, triangle). How many blocks in the set differ from the 'plastic medium red circle' in exactly two ways?(the "wood medium red square' in such a block)
I have come up with a solution for this
A generating function can represent the process of choosing a block. Each choice can match the 'plastic medium red circle' in one of its qualities $(1)$ or differ from it in $k$ different ways $(kx)$. Choosing the material is represented by the factor $(1+1x)$,
choosing the size by the factor $(1+2x)$, etc:$(1+x)(1+2x)(1+3x)^2$
Expanding out the first two factors and the square:$(1+3x+2x^2)(1+6x+9x^2)$....By expanding further we can find the coefficient of $x^2$, which represents the number of blocks differing from the original block in exactly two ways. We don't have to expand it completely, but choose the terms which will be multiplied together to result in a constant multiple of $x^2$ = $1*9 + 3*6 + 2*1 = 29$
but.....
when I come up with another idea of solving this which is using combinatorics in this question. I am stuck in one way or another and not ending with the number 29
can someone help me with using combinatorics and anything else?

Can you use latex to format your math equation, see here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

You trailed off mid question.  "How many blocks in the set differ from the 'plastic medium red circle' in exactly" isn't a complete sentence.

Also, I don’t think it is related to complex analysis, either.

More broadly, the numbers involved are so small here that it's hard to imagine that setting up generating functions would be necessary.

@lulu - presumably  "How many blocks in the set differ from the 'plastic medium red circle' in exactly two ways"

@lulu i have rectified the question
How many blocks in the set differ from the 'plastic medium red circle' in exactly two ways?(the "wood medium red square' in such a block)

Ok, so just list the $6$ possible pairs of differing characteristics and sum.  Symmetry helps as two of the characteristics have four options each.  Not sure what else you might want...the general problem, where you have $n$ characteristics each with differing numbers of options and you seek to vary exactly $k$ of them seems very hard.

First of all, I am surprised that the question was downvoted.  Alternatively, I am surprised that the downvote was not lifted after the editing.  The OP (i.e. original poster) presented a reasonable question, and then tried to solve it with generating functions.
As lulu indicated in the comments, the numbers are small enough that generating functions seem like overkill.
The number of materials, colors, sizes, and shapes is 2,3,4,4, respectively.
So, you want to enumerate each of the following:

Number of ways of differing from base object by material and color: 
$(2-1) \times (3-1) = 2.$

Number of ways of differing from base object by material and size: 
$(2-1) \times (4-1) = 3.$

Number of ways of differing from base object by material and shape: 
$(2-1) \times (4-1) = 3.$

Number of ways of differing from base object by color and size: 
$(3-1) \times (4-1) = 6.$

Number of ways of differing from base object by color and shape: 
$(3-1) \times (4-1) = 6.$

Number of ways of differing from base object by size and shape: 
$(4-1) \times (4-1) = 9.$


Final Computation:
$$2 + 3 + 3 + 6 + 6 + 9 = 29.$$

Got it...... tq

You are looking for exactly two differences out of the four possibilities. You decided to use the generating function $$(1+x)(1+2x)(1+3x)^2$$
which expanded would be $$1+9x+29x^2+39x^3+18x^4$$
and the coefficient of $x^2$ is $29$, which you seem to say is your desired result.
An equivalent result is to say that if you subtract $1$ from each of $2,3,4,4$ you get $1,2,3,3$ ways of having a particular difference, and then the answer of the number of ways of having exactly two differences and exactly two not different can also be found as $1\times 2+1 \times 3 + 1 \times 3 +2\times 3+2 \times 3+3\times 3 =29$.

@riteshwar I think $1\times 2+1 \times 3 + 1 \times 3 +2\times 3+2 \times 3+3\times 3 =29$ is a combinatorial result.  How many ways of of having just  material and size different, plus how many ways of having just material and colour different, plus ...

nvm i didnt read the below thing
TQSM

can u briefly explain it i cannot get it

@riteshwar Suppose you kept wood and square the same but changed medium to small or large (two possibilities) and changed red to blue, green or yellow (three possibilities).  Then there would be $2\times 3$ ways of doing that.  Similarly for the other choices.
